# How to read CSV file using pandas on mac?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Why am I not able to read a CSV file on my Mac?

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv('new_weather.csv')
csv
```

Its gives me Error

```
[Errno 2] File b'new_weather.csv' does not exist: b'new_weather.csv'
```

Comment: maybe file is in different folder? try full path `pd.read_csv('/full/path/to/new_weather.csv')`

Answer (score 3):

Your file doesn't exist in current directory. Enter the full path of the file and it's all set :)

Comment: but how shld i add path in mac? '/ ' is not supported for mac

Comment: @MeetBhanushali I am a mac user. I can do `ls -l  /Users/sampathm/Desktop/printout1.png` in my terminal for a file in my desktop `printout1.png`. Mac is a Darwin linux OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Firstly your desired file is not present in your current working directory. You can import it by entering the full path of your file.

You can follow these simple steps to do it:

1. Go to you desired file and double tap on it, click on get info and copy the file path.
2. Enter the file path name in this format:

`h = pd.read_csv('/Users/himanshubhandari/Downloads/examples/ex1.csv')`